# Decomposition of order-$n$ tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then $V\otimes V\cong\mathbf{S}^2(V)\oplus\bigwedge^2(V)$.

The first summand on the right is the symmetric part of $V\otimes V$ and the second summand is the anti-symmetric part.  This identification of vector spaces is just the decomposition of order-$2$ tensors into their symmetric and anti-symmetric parts. (When $V$ is $1$-dimensional, we simply have $V\otimes V\cong\mathbf{S}^2(V)$.)

Without imposing assumptions on the dimension of $V$, what is the corresponding decomposition for $V\otimes V\otimes V$?  There should be an $\mathbf{S}^3(V)$ and a $\bigwedge^3(V)$, but what are the "mixed" terms?

Basically, I'd like a decomposition for $\bigotimes^nV$.

I'm not so interested in the (anti-)symmetrization formulas, i.e. I'm not worried about the specific isomorphism.

Comment: Do you know something about representation/character theory? You can view $V\otimes V$ as a representation for the symmetric group of order $2$, the decomposition then corresponds to grouping this into irreducible representations. For $V\otimes V\otimes V$ something similar holds, but you should be ready to accept that some of these irreducible representations will be higher dimensional.

Comment: I do and I accept.  But I'd like a direct answer.  If $V\otimes V\otimes V\cong\mathbf{S}^3(V)\oplus\bigwedge^3(V)\oplus B$, then I'd like an explicit characterization of the vector space $B$ in terms of symmetric and wedge powers of $V$. Thanks.

Comment: At the very least, I think a direct answer to the above question would be a good reference point for many people, not just myself.

Comment: can you give us some references, plz?

Comment: If I had the references, I'd probably have my answer!  ;-)